# Facebook App, counting likes, shares and comments

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I've been reading the facebook API and I've got a basic idea of its abilities. So I am not asking for anyone to do any research for me, I'm just asking if I got this concept correct.

I am working on the specs to an app that will have people share items on the timeline. I simply want to take a daily tally of the each item shared and want to know how many shares, likes and comments are made on it.

I believe I can do this with something similar to this:

```
$fql  = "SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, ";
```

Am I on the right track?

Comment: You'll need to call it `FROM link_stat WHERE url='HTTP://YOUR/URL'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be accomplished using the Graph API

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=YOUR_URL
```

something like:

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://www.yahoo.com
```

A sample of the returned values would be:

```
{
      "id": "http://www.yahoo.com",
      "shares": 200
```

}

You can get the following information with the like button

The number of likes of this URL 
The number of shares of this URL
The number of likes and comments on stories about this URL

The Like Button number is possible with the Graph API through the fql end-point (the link_stat table)

Here is a sample of the call URL to submit:

```
 https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT url, normalized_url, share_count, like_count, comment_count, total_count,commentsbox_count, comments_fbid, click_count FROM link_stat WHERE url='http://www.yahoo.com'
```